# Showing $f(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

Let $f_n:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that 
$$|f_n(x)|\leq M\:\:\:\: \text{for all $n\geq$ 1,$\:\:$$x\in(a,b),$}$$

for some constant $M>0$, and
$$\lim_{n\to{\infty}}f_n(x)=f(x)\:\:\:\text{for all $x\in(a,b)$ },$$

For some $f:(a,b)$. Moreover, for any small $\epsilon>0,$ the above convergence is uniform on $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon].  $ Show that $f(.)$ is continuous and 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^bf_n(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx.$$

If I can show $f(.)$ is continuous, then the rest would be so easy. let $\epsilon>0$. As $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon,]$, so $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon].$ Also, I can claim $ (f_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon].$ However, I don't know how to show $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,a+\epsilon] $ and $[b-\epsilon, b]$. I appreciate any hint, help or any link.

Comment: Uniformly Equicotinuous? Also, where do you want to show $f(.)$ is continuous?

Comment: Fix $x\in (a,b)$. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x\in [a+\varepsilon,b-\varepsilon]$. But the sequence converges uniformly in this set, and hence $f$ is continuous on that set, and so in particular in $x$. But $x\in (a,b)$ was arbitrary.

Comment: @gary Given any $\epsilon>0$, you can find a $\delta$ such that for any $n$ and any $x$, we have $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$. Basically, all the $f_n$ are uniformly continuous, and given some $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ that works for all of them simultaneously. If you fix $x$ before you find $\delta$, you get just equicontinuity.

Comment: I thought I need to show $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Make sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. As regards $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^bf_n(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x)dx$, note that
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b}(f_n(x)-f(x))dx \right|= \left|\int_{a}^{a+\epsilon} \right|+\left|\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon}  \right|+
\left|\int_{b-\epsilon}^{b}  \right|\leq 2M\epsilon+\epsilon +2M\epsilon$$
where for the second integral we use uniform convergence and for the first and the third integral we use the the uniform boundedness.